# My Pi freezes during install

Tags: raspbian, noobs

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 B and I used *NOOBS* and *NOOBS Lite* to install Jessie but when I selected *Jessie* and *install*, it starts to install but then says "*zeroing start of each partition*" and as I try to move the mouse, it stops moving. I really don't know if it is a bug in NOOBS or a faulty RPi.

Please tell me if I need to do something differently or what's wrong with it.

Comment: Quite often an insufficient power supply is the cause of symptoms like random freezes.

Comment: Your memory card might be faulty.

Comment: /_!_\ That error message sound like the response of `fdisk` when it creates a partition - this is a hang-over from MSDos on PC days where that OSs `fdisk` or `format` commands wrote or expected some extra stuff at the beginning of the drive and the only way to be sure the new partition would be "recognised" by some *broken* OS's tools as being changed was to nuke the first sector of the partition to remove any previous information that would confuse them - hence that message...!

Answer (score 3):

As with joan's comment, I had a similar problem with the NOOBS Raspbian install getting stuck on the extracting file system error.

After trying a new power supply and reflashing the SD with NOOBS it has since worked without a hitch.

It seems that if the Pi does not have a sufficient power input then the install will fail, which seemed to be my problem and I had already tried 3 seperate installs on my SD card.

If you don't have an official Pi power supply, I would recommend you getting one as this was what was causing my issue, as the voltage was 0.1v lower than the 5.1v of the official power supply.

Comment: I had the same problem. A brand new 2.5A official power supply couldn't sufficiently power the ZeroW, but a 2.0A Samsung charger worked fine. Sometimes you just have a faulty power supply.

Comment: Same problem here, stuck at 1% while extracting filesystem. Unplugged power cord, plugged in again and at next reboot it went all the way. Worth a shot, before changing power supply or SD card (a 32 GB samsung, for the record).

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. Then what I do is:

- Take out the SD card and format it (dont forget to turn on size adjusment)
- Copy the OS to SD card as usual
- When I plug in the Raspberry Pi, and NOOBS starts to boot, I turn on my WiFi connection (behind the install button)
- and my installing goes on as usual.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. A new SD card did the trick for me. Try that.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange Network! I didn't -1 you but I think I understand the sentiment.  Your response does not really *add* to the sum of knowledge on this subject.  Perhaps if you (***and the OP***) indicated the make and model of the SD cards that were being used then your contribution may be considered in a more constructive way?

Answer (score -2):

Changed from a Nokia charger to a decent Samsung charger and it stopped crashing at 24%

Comment: This may be a power issue, however if the OP is not using a nokia charger they are likely to think your answer is irrelevant.